# How convert Map[String, Any] to Json?

Tags: json, scala, lift

I have invoke on JObject:

```
jObject.values
```

So i get Map[String, Any]. I modify this map and getting new instance of Map[String, Any]. And now i wont achieve something reverse to 'values' method: I wont convert my Map[String, Any] to JObject (or json string)

Comment: you need to put what you have tried to do..so that it will be easy to help you!

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat tricky, because by calling `.values` you lose the type information associated with the fields (hence why the value type of the map is `Any`).

In order to get a `JObject`, you need to pass a `List[JField]` into the constructor.  So you'll need to convert each map entry (`(String, Any)`) into a `JField`.  Mapping the name is trivial; the challenge is converting an `Any` into a `JValue`.

You could probably do something with pattern-matching or type-checking (e.g. if the value is an `Int`, cast it to int and wrap in a `JInt`), but as with all incomplete pattern matching this is going to be fragile - what do you do with non-primitives to wrap them back up the way they came out?

---

So I suggest that in general, the best way to do this is *not* to try to do this from the output of `.values` but pass the object around itself.  Once you've lost the type information, it's hard to get back definitively, and almost any solution will necessarily involve fragile guesswork.

Comment: thanks for response. Browsing lift-json code I have same conclusion but your post assured me